# How to match two locations in android programmatically?

Tags: android-location

I am building an android app with kotlin in which a user set a location and after user visit the set location some function will be triggered. I have built the app to get longitude and latitude of the user location and set location, but how to equal these two locations so the function will be triggered.

For example:- A user set a location whose Longitude & Latitude are 28.690040, 77.208654. After user reach this location the Longitude & Latitude are 28.690041, 77.208653. So by reaching the exact location, user's location is not equal to the set location and hence the function will not be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Your equality differs at the sixth decimal place, So what you can you do is to round up the `lat` and `long` to is to round up to 5 decimal place or even 4 decimal places.

According to an [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/measuring-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude) in the Stackexchange,

**fourth decimal place is worth up to 11 m**

**fifth decimal place is worth up to 1.1 m**

**sixth decimal place is worth up to 0.11 m**

So you should prefer `fifth` place or `fourth` place, depending on your requirement.